# alert before deleting sql databases through a winform application

Tags: .net, sql, winforms

I want that on a new installation of my .net winforms application,
which uses sql server 2005 express , 
it would drop old databases if exist but before deleting them , 
it alerts that the databases are empty or not by showing a message box i.e. they contain tables or not , & then creates new databases.

so whats the way to do this?

Comment: What are you asking? How to display a message box? How to list databases? How to tell if they're "empty"? How to drop databases?

Comment: Voting to close as too vague/broad. There's no specific question here, rather a task list for creating a new program.

Comment: @Adam Robinson : Sir, i am using this for checking if database exists: "if exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'software_setup')"
            + " drop database software_setup "
            + " create database software_setup";
  I want to know that how to return a value from this query and store it in a variable in C# and then display a messagebox, if this variable is true then it would display that database is not empty & if false then would display that databases are empty , you can simply delete them

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen : Dear Sir, Sir, i am using this for checking if database exists: "if exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'software_setup')" + " drop database software_setup " + " create database software_setup"; I want to know that how to return a value from this query and store it in a variable in C# and then display a messagebox, if this variable is true then it would display that database is not empty & if false then would display that databases are empty , you can simply delete them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a SQL Statement similar to this

`select 1 as DBExists from master.sys.databases where name = 'YourDatabaseNameGoesHere'`

If the dataset has rows, then the database exists!

You can find the number of tables in it (to see if it is empty or not) by running this SQL

`select COUNT (*) as NumTables from YourDatabaseNameGoesHere.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

If the dataset has rows, then display a messagebox with the appropriate message and then if the answer is "Yes" then drop the database.

Comment: @Downvoter: Leave a comment please

Comment: Well, what question did you answer here? (not me who downvoted though)

Comment: The `sysXXX` tables (actually, views) are deprecated. You should either use `sys` schema instead (in other words, `sys.databases`). More directly, though, this doesn't actually answer anything that the OP asked (which isn't clear to begin with).

Comment: @Adam Robinson: You're right. I changed it to use `Sys` schema

Comment: @Raj More: thanks a lot sir, can you give me the c# code, to how to match the result of the query :select COUNT (*) as NumTables from YourDatabaseNameGoesHere.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES , i mean , if it results zero (0), then how do i match that that the row contains the number zero. if (value of the query=0 ) display message box.

Comment: Simplest way would be to run a SqlCommand with the above query, use IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();, and if (reader.Read()), the database exists.

Comment: @DaveRead: sir, as you told, i have to execute command.ExecuteReader() before the if statement, so this first deletes & creates the databases before going to the if clause. and then it does not do anything

Comment: @DaveRead:   string q =  "if exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'software_setup')" + " drop database software_setup"+" create database software_setup";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, conn);
SqlDataReader reader  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{ MessageBox.Show("Databases already exist, you sure you want to delete them ","Databases Already Exist", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
   if (MessageBox.Show("Databases already exist, are you sure you want to delete them",
 "Databases Already Exist",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)== DialogResult.Yes) { reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();}

Comment: @DaveRead : sir, what should be my string ? please guide